# What component is this (not a capacitor but looks like it)?

Tags: components, identification

This component I think I got it from a CRT television (but also might come from a VGA card, sorry for not remembering).

It looks like a capacitor, but it does not have any Fahrad mentioning.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a fuse, rated at 1-1/4A 250VAC.

Specifically a slow-blow [Littelfuse](http://m.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/axial-radial-thru-hole-fuses/tr5-fuses/372.aspx) 372 series.

Answer (score 18):

The marking looks like:

> T1,25A250V

That fits with a **T**ime delay (i.e. slow blow) 1.25A 250V fuse.

Assuming that it hasn't blown, it should measure as a (near) short-circuit when you use a multimeter to measure its resistance.

Comment: I measure indeed around 0.7 or 0.8 ohm

Comment: Just a side note: household DMMs are entirely inaccurate for measuring shorts or near-shorts using the resistance setting. In other words, your 0.7/0.8 Ohm reading could have well over 100% error (or more) when measuring very small resistances. Ignore this comment if you didn't actually use a DMM to make that resistance measurement.

Comment: @DanLaks While you are correct, a ~0.7 ohm reading is more than enough to confirm that the fuse is not blown, unless you specifically suspected it was faulty for some reason.

Comment: @nitro2k01 completely agree. Just wanted to throw in that little factoid in case the OP thought the resistance value was accurate. The fuse is definitely not blown, but we don't know the exact resistance across it (except that it's very small).

Comment: @DanLaks useful to know, thanks. Also: '"factoid": an item of unreliable information that is reported and repeated so often that it becomes accepted as fact.'